# python for loop and its generator issue

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am trying to generate some link.

NOTE: THERE IS PROBLEM WITH return vs print.

when i write the code with with return, it is only return one linK:

run this code:

```
import requests
import re

wikiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States'


state_pat = re.compile(r'title=\"(\w+)\">')

def get_page_content(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text

def link_generator(wikiurl):
    content = get_page_content(wikiurl)
    names = state_pat.findall(content)
    for i in names:
        return 'https://www.local.com/business/results/listing.cfm?s=tile+and+grout+cleaning&ar=' + i + '%2CNY&gsp=ZFZWU1RaU09zWGNYdjFEV1l2ZHFLNVZUUFRPT3c3a21lbFVCbERQOU5VS3p6ai9DRXNMa29PcVZ0ZVV0TXZLM01wUVFUUHZYK2lrMnB5VGJyMHZJeUNoK1dXaUoxZ1NKT3AxbVlJOGN1aVBEb1NRMzlCemdDVHh5aGd3eU5DYUpKWDRtNFVQR0llOFJibUhQR3pSV3ppWFR4ekJoRVltL29UdFQ0MW9KUS9IenJrcjVBMUt3bkErRnlSVnFjRnZ0TjhRWEdET0FuZWRVUGNkemdxUlkzOUYyUjZXbHBzQWRMY3hEUTY4WmtnYkRsSkEvazBrVVY5d0NmSVVMaWp0WnNDNmFsZFNzMitWeHZDYTg2YmJwRGQzSisvOUJaYWNBaFdUd21LaWJpNk9veS9OT1N1VE5DV3RUNDIxdkY5NmZ4bWFVcWtLc1BlVkNRNlEvSG4ydER1T1ZkcXk4Um5BWU5kUU9UZnVOUE9BPQ%253D%253D&lwfilter=&wsrt=&wpn='


a = link_generator(wikiurl)
print(a)
```

and if i run this code adding a print into fuction, it returns all the link, why? i need all the link with `return`

run this code: you will see different:

```
import requests
import re

wikiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States'


state_pat = re.compile(r'title=\"(\w+)\">')

def get_page_content(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text

def link_generator(wikiurl):
    content = get_page_content(wikiurl)
    names = state_pat.findall(content)
    for i in names:
        print('https://www.local.com/business/results/listing.cfm?s=tile+and+grout+cleaning&ar=' + i + '%2CNY&gsp=ZFZWU1RaU09zWGNYdjFEV1l2ZHFLNVZUUFRPT3c3a21lbFVCbERQOU5VS3p6ai9DRXNMa29PcVZ0ZVV0TXZLM01wUVFUUHZYK2lrMnB5VGJyMHZJeUNoK1dXaUoxZ1NKT3AxbVlJOGN1aVBEb1NRMzlCemdDVHh5aGd3eU5DYUpKWDRtNFVQR0llOFJibUhQR3pSV3ppWFR4ekJoRVltL29UdFQ0MW9KUS9IenJrcjVBMUt3bkErRnlSVnFjRnZ0TjhRWEdET0FuZWRVUGNkemdxUlkzOUYyUjZXbHBzQWRMY3hEUTY4WmtnYkRsSkEvazBrVVY5d0NmSVVMaWp0WnNDNmFsZFNzMitWeHZDYTg2YmJwRGQzSisvOUJaYWNBaFdUd21LaWJpNk9veS9OT1N1VE5DV3RUNDIxdkY5NmZ4bWFVcWtLc1BlVkNRNlEvSG4ydER1T1ZkcXk4Um5BWU5kUU9UZnVOUE9BPQ%253D%253D&lwfilter=&wsrt=&wpn=')


a = link_generator(wikiurl)
print(a)
```

Comment: A function *ends* when it `return`s.

Comment: did you read my full problem and go through its code?

Comment: The first time your loop is run it returns the URL and the function ends. When you replace the return with a print function it prints every cycle of the loop but does not end the function each time

Comment: Now i want to get all the link with return, how can i do it?

Comment: Build a list and return that at the end.

Answer (score 2):

When you issue a `return` statement in a function it doesn't execute any further lines and returns to its caller. If you want to iteratively return items in a generator you can replace `return` with `yield`. Alternatively collect the results as a list and return the list.

You then need to change your final line when you're calling this to:

```
a = list(link_generator(wikiurl))
```

to unpack your generator

Comment: Not works yield, same, it retrun this: <generator object link_generator at 0x7f6b45b77f68>

Comment: See my edit, you have to unpack your generator because they are lazily evaluated

Comment: Thans, got it, much appreciated